# Consider the string $(∀x)(∀y)(f(x) = y → ((∀z)g(z) = f(x) ≡ (∀z)g(z) = y))$

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Is this well-formed formula a tautology?

I am having trouble finding examples to help me work through these types of problems. I was hoping someone could help me out.

I think, using abstraction, this can be written as:

$$(∀x)(∀y)(p → (q ≡ q_1))$$

which can be further abstracted to a simple boolean variable such as $p_1$.
Which I say is not a tautology.

But then I am asked:

Can you prove $$(∀x)(∀y)(f(x) = y → ((∀z)g(z) = f(x) ≡ (∀z)g(z) = y))$$ in predicate logic? If so, give a proof, if not, explain why.

I know that if the above were a tautology, then the above would be immediately provable. But if it is not a tautology, what do I say?

Can I say it is not provable because it is not a tautology and therefore not an axiom... I don't know what to say here.

Thanks in advance for any help or thoughts.

Comment: What is your definition of a tautology? A formula that is true in every model? In that case, Gödel's Completeness Theorem says that the tautologies are precisely the provable statements in predicate logic.

Comment: Many people, including me, use "tautology" to mean "valid because of only the propositional structure", but other people use "tautology" to mean the same as "logically valid". The formula in your question is logically valid, but more than the propositional structure is involved; equality plays a crucial role in making this formula valid. So to answer your question it is essential to know which meaning of "tautology" your teacher/textbook/conscience uses. I suspect the intended meaning is the first one I mentioned, propositional validity, not first-order validity.

Comment: In any case, to prove that your formula is valid in predicate logic, you'll need to use axioms and/or rules of inference about equality, because, as I said, the validity of the formula depends crucially on the meaning of equality.

Comment: Well-formed ? Maybe... maybe not. Why the quantified variable are $x,y$ if the formula has $x_1,y_1$ ?

Comment: Obviously $(∀x)(∀y)(p→(q≡q_1))$ is **not** a tautology because the propositional formula $(p→(q≡q_1))$ is **not** a tautology.

Comment: sorry for the x1's and y1's.

I edited them out.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is a [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity#Valid_formula) formula of [First-order logic with equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

Here is the derivation:

1) $f(x)=y$ --- premise

2) $(∀z)(g(z)=f(x))$ --- assumed [a]

3) $g(z)=f(x)$ --- from 2) by [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

4) $g(z)=y$ --- from 1) and 3) bt [transitivity of equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms)

5) $(∀z)(g(z)=y)$ --- from 4) by [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

> 6) $(∀z)(g(z)=f(x)) \to (∀z)(g(z)=y)$ --- from 2) and 5) by [Conditional Proof (i.e. Implication introduction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)

In the same way, assuming $(∀z)(g(z)=y)$ we derive :

> 7) $(∀z)(g(z)=y) \to (∀z)(g(z)=f(x))$.

Thus, we derive, by [Bi-conditional introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction) :

> 8) $(∀z)(g(z)=y) \leftrightarrow (∀z)(g(z)=f(x))$

and finally we conclude with:

> > 9) $(∀x)(∀y)[(f(x)=y) \to ((∀z)(g(z)=y) \leftrightarrow (∀z)(g(z)=f(x)))]$ --- from 19 and 8) by Conditional introduction (discharging the premise) and Generalization twice.

Having proved it, by [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Soundness) of the calculus, we conclude that the formula is valid.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your $x_1$ is just $x$, and $y_1$ is just $y$, the statement is valid.

Your abstraction does indeed not show this, however, since your $p$ abstracts away from the crucial identity $f(x) = y$ that makes this a valid statement.

Here is a proof in Fitch:

[image]

Comment: @johnsonandjohnson You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y→((∀z)g(z)=f(x)≡(∀z)g(z)=y)

(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y)→(∀x)(∀y)((∀z)g(z)=f(x)≡(∀z)g(z)=y)  (Theorem)

(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y)  |--  (∀x)(∀y)((∀z)g(z)=f(x)≡(∀z)g(z)=y)  (deduction theorem)

Using a ping pong argument:

(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y)  |--  (∀x)(∀y)((∀z)g(z)=f(x)→(∀z)g(z)=y)

(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y)  |--  (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x)→(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=y (Theorem)

(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y),(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x)|-- (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=y (deduction)

(∀z)(∀x)(∀y)(f(x)=y),(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x)|-- (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=y (axiom)

(1) (∀z)(∀x)(∀y)f(x)=y      (Hypothesis)

(2) (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x)   (Hypothesis)

(3) f(x)=y                  (Specialization (1))

(4) g(z)=f(x)               (Specialization (2))

(5) y=g(z)                  (Transitivity (3) and (4))

(6) (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=y      (Generalization x,y,z dnof in (1) or (2))

(∀x)(∀y)f(x)=y  |--  (∀z)(∀x)(∀y)g(z)=y → (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x)

(∀x)(∀y)f(x)=y,(∀z)(∀x)(∀y)g(z)=y  |-- (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x) (deduction)

(∀z)(∀x)(∀y)f(x)=y,(∀z)(∀x)(∀y)g(z)=y |-- (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x) (axiom)

(1) (∀z)(∀x)(∀y)f(x)=y    (Hypothesis)

(2) (∀z)(∀x)(∀y)g(z)=y    (Hypothesis)

(3) f(x)=y                (Specialization (1))

(4) g(z)=y                (Specialization (2))

(5) g(z)=f(x)             (Transitivity (3) and (4))

(6) (∀x)(∀y)(∀z)g(z)=f(x) (Generalization x,y,z dnof in (1) or (2))